# Why js and css file is invalid when they are imported on the server

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a website which import some js and css files on the head tag, but when I open the website by chrome,The entire page layout is completely wrong and looks like js and css files is invalid. Who can help me? Thanks.

By the way, JS consolo don't have any error messages. Every js css and image files have been loaded in the network tab.

```
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<script src="http://xmumap-code.stor.sinaapp.com/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://xmumap-code.stor.sinaapp.com/js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://xmumap-code.stor.sinaapp.com/js/swiper.jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://xmumap-code.stor.sinaapp.com/css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://xmumap-code.stor.sinaapp.com/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://xmumap-code.stor.sinaapp.com/css/swiper.min.css">
</head>
```

Comment: Show us the page? It looks more like your browser is caching some information not refreshing the CSS.

Comment: I can not upload images because of reputation

Comment: Show us the link to the website maybe?

Comment: http://xmumap-code.stor.sinaapp.com/15-09-29560a833ac5600.html

Answer (score 0):

try including your bootstrap.min.css file before all the CSS file gets loaded.